# RF24 Network and Payload

Tags: nrf24l01+, network

i struggle to figure out the max payload for the RF24 Network library without payload fragmentation.
It uses a NetworkHeader with the Attributes from_node, to_node, id, type and reserved.
This must be send to and lowers the amount of Bytes of the payload.

Can any one tell me how many Bytes I can write without sending two packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the source code:

```cpp
const static unsigned int max_frame_payload_size = MAX_FRAME_SIZE-sizeof(RF24NetworkHeader);
```

that would be `24 bytes`. Maximum lenght of payload for NRF24L01+ is 32 bytes and the `RF24NetworkHeader` seem to be 8 bytes long. So you can send up to 24 bytes in one package.

**EDIT:**
Here is the stripped `RF24NetworkHeader` declaration code from which can be seen `sizeof(RF24NetworkHeader)` is 8 bytes.

```cpp
struct RF24NetworkHeader {
  uint16_t from_node;           // 2 bytes
  uint16_t to_node;             // 2 bytes
  uint16_t id;                  // 2 bytes
  unsigned char type;           // 1 byte
  unsigned char reserved;       // 1 byte
  static uint16_t next_id;      // static member doesn't count for sizeof()
  RF24NetworkHeader() {}
  RF24NetworkHeader(uint16_t _to, unsigned char _type = 0): to_node(_to), id(next_id++), type(_type) {}
  const char* toString(void) const;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I hoped it is written somewhere in the library docs but this approach sounds very plausible too.

Comment: Maybe it even is written somewhere but I've never used Arduino and I don't even have one so I don't know :-) I've been using AVRs for years but only with AVR Studio and ISP programming. Now that you said, if you look at the [source of the .h file](https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24Network/blob/master/RF24Network.h), there is the: `The actual frame put over the air consists of a header (8-bytes) and a message payload (Up to 24-bytes)`, line in the comments so it might have been picked by some doc generators.